# Grain Distribution Graph in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to make a graph with matplotlib like the one shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQO5w.png). The problem I'm running into, is the top part of the graph. I already tried the table option from matplotlib but couldn't get it to work. Another idea is plotting my data over a backgroundimage made with inkscape (Problem is, I don't have any idea how to reference the backgroundimage so that the plot is scientifically correct/precise). So my questions are:

1. Do you think it is possible with the table option from matplotlib (and i should dig deeper)?
2. Or is my backgroundimage idea the better choice?
3. Or is there a complete different approach?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's definitely possible to use a matplotlib table. The biggest problem is that those do not allow for column-spanning cells,  but you would still get close to the desired result. Alternatively, drawing a table by placing lines and texts at certain positions is also possible. I would not recommend placing a background image in matplotlib. On the other hand you could put the plot into inkscape and draw the table there.

Comment: If the graph contains few points and lines, can you output it to SVG? Then edit the file to add the table header.

Comment: By the way, it appears to be your first question here. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: @theduck Thank you very much for your help. The reason i want to do this, is a reusable website application. So i think the "placing lines and text" is the better choice.